# Show percentage progress dialog when parsing json using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, progressdialog

Need to show a progress bar having percentage while parsing data from a URL using retrofit library.
Actually, more than 8k data is being sent in the URL so my requirement is to show percentage dialog while parsing data. Most of the code available is related to download/uploading files while showing percentage progress dialog. So I am not able to understand how can I incorporate the same while parsing JSON from URL.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        APIInterface service = ServiceGenerator.getRetrofit().create(APIInterface.class);
        Call<Comment> call = service.getHeroList();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Comment>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Comment> call, Response<Comment> response) {
                Log.e("Response", response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Comment> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
}


public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static Gson gson;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        httpClient.protocols(Util.immutableList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
        httpClient.connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://www.json-generator.com/api/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}

public class Comment {
    @SerializedName("postId")
    @Expose
    private Integer postId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;

    public Integer getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    public void setPostId(Integer postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}

public interface APIInterface {

    @GET("json/get/ceZASEJMRK?indent=2")
    Call<Comment> getHeroList();

}
```

Comment: Do you want to show progress while downloading or while parsing the result? Gson will do the parsing for you btw

Comment: just want to show the dialog having percentage while parsing the json